# Google maps theme

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, android-theme

I have implemented Google maps in my Android application and everything looked clean until few days. Previously the maps looked like the below image

[image]

Now the map has a new look similar to image below

[image]
I have not changed or updated anything in the implemention, yet there are dark lines on the map which makes it difficult to read the places.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Note: I have downloaded the images from Google for reference, please ignore the xml layout changes.

Comment: The second image is from Uber. Can you replace with your app's screens

Comment: @Sreehari the map looks similar to the second image in my app also.

Comment: have you tried TERRAIN view of Google Map map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
      map.invalidate();?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess u might added map theme, if added please remove or change theme

```
    //Custom Theme
    MapStyleOptions style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this.context, R.raw.my_map_style);
    map.setMapStyle(style);
```

Changing theme Please refer [here](https://hackernoon.com/using-custom-styles-with-google-maps-android-api-e1e5ec3ac7e9).

Create theme from [here](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/).

Answer (score 6):

First go the official side i.e https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/
and get the json for your style value and copy to the raw folder in resources

And then apply on your onMapready() like this

```
MapStyleOptions mapStyleOptions = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.style_json);
mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(mapStyleOptions);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Rewrite in style json file. try to different color code change.**

> java code

```
MapStyleOptions mapStyleOptions = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(activity, 
R.raw.map_style);
googleMap.setMapStyle(mapStyleOptions);
```

> raw/map_style.json file

```
 [
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "saturation": "40"
      },
      {
        "lightness": "5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "hue": "#ff0000"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#000000"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "simplified"
      },
      {
        "color": "#cb561a"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#858585"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
        "color": "#858585"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
        "color": "#00467f"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#a8a8a8"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
        "hue": "#ffc800"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "hue": "#ffc800"
      },
      {
        "saturation": "25"
      },
      {
        "lightness": "42"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
        "lightness": "8"
      },
      {
        "gamma": "0.75"
      },
      {
        "saturation": "-6"
      },
      {
        "hue": "#ffc600"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
        "weight": "1.77"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#aeaeae"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
        "color": "#8bd188"
      },
      {
        "lightness": "41"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#949595"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "saturation": -100
      },
      {
        "lightness": 45
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
        "hue": "#ff0000"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#686868"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "simplified"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "weight": "1.03"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "simplified"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#b3e9ff"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "saturation": "-35"
      },
      {
        "color": "#b6e0f3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#86c1ea"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use **Style JSON file**. Here i have [attached](https://gist.github.com/saveendhiman/866e63dc45c3422254f203d42ae072d4) sample json. You can download and apply with your project.

```
try {
     boolean success = mMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.maps_style));

     // mMap : It is the object of a map. 

     if (!success) {
         Log.e("tag", "Style parsing failed.");
        }
 } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Can't find style. :" + e);
 }
```

You can take style from [google.developer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) website too.
Thanks hope this will help you.